# Are there performance benefits to using WaitForSeconds vs checking elapsed time in FixedUpdate in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#

I was considering that perhaps just checking the time and then doing some work in the Update function might look cleaner than calculating how long to wait for and calling yield new WaitForSeconds() on two interleaving processes, so I became curious whether there is a huge difference between the two options.

Doesn't WaitForSeconds just work by calling an iterator after a certain amount of time has elapsed? So I assume that a timer is checked on each update, and when the time has elapsed, the IEnumerator's movenext function is called.

However, I thought it couldn't hurt to ask someone just in case there is some huge difference in performance.

Comment: `WaitForSeconds` does give the engine the option at least to use some type of scheduling system, where it doesn't need to test every coroutine every frame. I don't know whether it actually uses this method though. It may be possible to glean this from [its decompiled dlls](https://github.com/MattRix/UnityDecompiled)

Comment: I think WaitForSeconds uses the time scale, so they might be different. Hence Unity introduced a WaitForSecondsRealtime in verison 5.4.